# Isomorphism of direct sum of modules: if $M \oplus M \simeq N \oplus N$, must $M \simeq N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Is possible to have $M\oplus M \simeq N \oplus N$ and $M$ not isomorphic to $N$, where $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules?

Comment: This is false, it was answered here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24697/isomorphism-between-direct-sum-of-modules

Comment: @user353673 Consider posting an answer!

Comment: A good question at this point would be: does there exist a counterexample for every ring $R$ (unital or not)?  Also, we can restrict to the discussion of unitary modules in case $R$ is unital (but we can also look at non-unitary modules as well).

Comment: See [this example](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/513756/121097), and try to use Search before posting.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27744/does-g-oplus-g-cong-h-oplus-h-imply-g-cong-h-in-general?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

The following MathOverflow [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24697/isomorphism-between-direct-sum-of-modules) discusses the question and several counterexamples are presented. Perhaps there are even more elementary ones?

If $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated and $R$ is a principal domain, then the assertion is true. This was discussed in the following [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842851/m-oplus-m-simeq-n-oplus-n-then-m-simeq-n?rq=1).